# Shadow mapping shader

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, fragment-shader, shadow-mapping

I've got a shader that implements shadow mapping like this:

```
#version 430 core

out vec4 color;

in VS_OUT {
    vec3 N;
    vec3 L;
    vec3 V;
    vec4 shadow_coord;
} fs_in;

layout(binding = 0) uniform sampler2DShadow shadow_tex;

uniform vec3 light_ambient_albedo = vec3(1.0);
uniform vec3 light_diffuse_albedo = vec3(1.0);
uniform vec3 light_specular_albedo = vec3(1.0);

uniform vec3 ambient_albedo = vec3(0.1, 0.1, 0.2);
uniform vec3 diffuse_albedo = vec3(0.4, 0.4, 0.8);
uniform vec3 specular_albedo = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
uniform float specular_power = 128.0;

void main(void) {
    //color = vec4(0.4, 0.4, 0.8, 1.0);

    //normalize
    vec3 N = normalize(fs_in.N);
    vec3 L = normalize(fs_in.L);
    vec3 V = normalize(fs_in.V);

    //calculate R
    vec3 R = reflect(-L, N);

    //calcualte ambient
    vec3 ambient = ambient_albedo * light_ambient_albedo;

    //calculate diffuse
    vec3 diffuse = max(dot(N, L), 0.0) * diffuse_albedo * light_diffuse_albedo;

    //calcualte spcular
    vec3 specular = pow(max(dot(R, V), 0.0), specular_power) * specular_albedo * light_specular_albedo;

    //write color
    color = textureProj(shadow_tex, fs_in.shadow_coord) * vec4(ambient + diffuse + specular, 0.5);
    //if in shadow, then multiply color by 0.5 ^^, except alpha
}
```

What I want to do is to check first if the fragment is indeed in the shadow, and only **then** change the color (halve it, such that it becomes halfway between fully black and original color).

However how to check if the `textureProj(...)` result is indeed in shadow, as far as I know it returns a normalized `float` value.

Would something like `textureProj(...) > 0.9999` suffice already? I know that it can returns values other than zero or one if you are using multisampling and I'd like behaviour that will not just break at one point.

The outputting vertex shader:

```
#version 430 core

layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;

layout(location = 0) uniform mat4 model_matrix;
layout(location = 1) uniform mat4 view_matrix;
layout(location = 2) uniform mat4 proj_matrix;
layout(location = 3) uniform mat4 shadow_matrix;

out VS_OUT {
    vec3 N;
    vec3 L;
    vec3 V;
    vec4 shadow_coord;
} vs_out;

uniform vec4 light_pos = vec4(-20.0, 7.5, -20.0, 1.0);

void main(void) {
    vec4 local_light_pos = view_matrix * light_pos;
    vec4 p = view_matrix * model_matrix * position;

    //normal
    vs_out.N = vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

    //light vector
    vs_out.L = local_light_pos.xyz - p.xyz;

    //view vector
    vs_out.V = -p.xyz;

    //light space coordinates
    vs_out.shadow_coord = shadow_matrix * position;

    gl_Position = proj_matrix * p;
}
```

Note that the fragment shader is for terrain, and the vertex shader is for the floor, so there might be minor inconsistencies between the two, but they should be non relevant.

`shadow_matrix` is an uniform passed in as `bias_matrix * light_projection_matrix * light_view_matrix * light_model_matrix`.

Comment: How is multisampling supposed to change the result of `textureProj (...)`? There is no such thing as a `sampler2DShadowMS`. The only thing that will change your texture lookup from returning **0.0** or **1.0** is texture filtering. I have explained this in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

`textureProj (...)` does not return a normalized floating-point value. It does return a single `float` if you use it on a `sampler<1D|2D|2DRect>Shadow`, but this value represents the result of a depth test. **1.0** = pass, **0.0** = fail.

Now, the interesting thing to note here, and the reason returning a `float` for a shadow sampler is meaningful at all has to do with filtering the shadow map. If you use a `GL_LINEAR` filter mode on the shadow map together with a shadow sampler, GL will actually pick the 4 closest texels in the shadow map and perform 4 independent depth tests.

Each depth test ***still*** has a binary result, but GL will return a weighted average of the result of all 4 tests (based on distance from the ideal sample location). So if you use `GL_LINEAR` in conjunction with a shadow sampler, you will have a value that lies somewhere in-between **0.0** and **1.0** representing the average occlusion for the 4 nearest depth samples.

I should point out that your use of `textureProj (...)` looks potentially wrong to me. The coordinate it uses is a 4D vector consisting of (`s`,`t`,`r`) [projected coordinates] and (`q`) [depth value to test]. I do not see anywhere in your code where you are assigning `q` a depth value. If you could edit your question to include the vertex/geometry shader that is outputting `shadow_coord`, that would help.

Comment: I've edited the question to include the vertex shader that produces them. Most of it is still a copy from the book I've read, I'm starting to think their shadowmapping example is wrong on all sides. Code can be found on https://github.com/openglsuperbible/sb6code/tree/master/src/shadowmapping and shaders on https://github.com/openglsuperbible/sb6code/tree/master/bin/media/shaders/shadowmapping.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

Get the distance from each vertex of your model to the light.

Send this distance to your fragment shader.

Compare the distance to the value stored in your shadow map sampler (I assume this texture stores the depth values of your scene from the camera's point of view?)

If the distance is greater than the sampler, the point is in shadow. Else, it is not.

If this is confusing, here's a pair of tutorials that should help:
http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial23/tutorial23.html
http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial24/tutorial24.html

Comment: Can you explain why I am using `textureProj` over the normal `texture` method? I have also found this in a book, but I still do not really know why.

Comment: I haven't used textureProj before, to be honest. I've read up on it and it performs a texture sampling with projection, which means that the coordinates you pass into the function are projected (i.e, if you pass in 3 elements x,y,z, textureProj calculates x/z, y/z before sampling the texture). Why this projection is necessary is a bit beyond the scope of a comment :) but these links should help out a bit: http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/manglsl/xhtml/textureProj.xml

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection 

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates

Comment: If you're still confused about projection, I would definitely pick up a book or two on 3d math. It's not as heavy and intimidating as it seems and it will help out out immeasurably. I recommend this one:
http://www.amazon.com/Math-Primer-Graphics-Development-Edition/dp/1568817231